# How to get the entire document HTML as a string?

Tags: javascript, html, document, tostring

Is there a way in JS to get the entire HTML within the *html* tags, as a string?

```
document.documentElement.??
```

Comment: The only correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string#answer-35917295 (**stop up-voting inner/outerHTML answers, they do NOT provide the entire source!**)

Comment: `document.body.parentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: @John what don't they provide?

Comment: @bluejayke the doctype and <html> tag itself are not included in innerHTML, and the doctype is not present in outerHTML. See paulo62’s answer; it gives the output of both

Comment: Op did not ask for the entire source, please calm down John.

Comment: **Stop upvoting John's bolded comment!** The answer he links to replaces `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` and so it breaks all your inline `<script>` tags! You should use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` instead, but note that it doesn't grab `<!DOCTYPE html>`, so you'll need to add that yourself.

Answer (score 412, accepted):

Get the root `<html>` element with [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) then get its [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```js
const txt = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(txt);
```

or its [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to get the `<html>` tag as well

```js
const txt = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
alert(txt);
```

Comment: outerHTML doesn't get the doctype.

Comment: worked like a charm! thank you! is there any way to get the size of any/all files linked to the document as well including js and css files?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: You could [get the doctype separately](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162353/157385) and prepend it to the markup string. Not ideal, I know, but possible.

Comment: note that neither this nor none of these answers necessarily give you content that is the exact hash equivalent of saving the page to a file or the file generated by view-source. It seems the DOM normalizes some fields from the literal response content, like capitalising DOCTYPE headers

Answer (score 143):

You can do

```js
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)
```

in browsers newer than IE 9

See https://caniuse.com/xml-serializer

Comment: This was the *first* **correct answer** according to date/time stamps. Parts of the page such as the XML declaration will *not* be included and browsers will manipulate the code when using the other "answers". This is the *only* post that should be up-voted (dos's posted three days later). People need to pay attention!

Comment: This is not entirely correct since it serializeToString performs an HTML encode. For example if your code contains styles defining fonts such as "Times New Roman", Times, serif the quotes will get html encoded. Perhaps that is not important to some of you but to me it is...

Comment: @John well the OP actually asks for "the entire HTML _within_ the html tags". And the selected best answer by Colin Burnett does achieve this. This particular answer (Erik's) will include the html tags and the doctype.

That said, this was totally a diamond in the rough for me and exactly what I was looking for! Your comment helped too because it made me spend more time with this answer, so thanks :)

Comment: I think people should be careful with this one, specifically because it returns a value that is not the actual html that your browser receives. In my case, it added attributes to the `html` tag that the server never actually sent :(

Comment: For some reason this fails in Edge

Comment: I use this but no success for getting whole html source of my page...…:(

Comment: Very poor browser support unfortunately https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer

Comment: It's supported in every browser. How is this poor browser support?

Comment: @onassar If you page JavaScript modifies the document, it won't be the same as what the server sent. Or do you experience this even if your page has no JavaScript?

Comment: **WARNING:** This breaks `<script>` tags! It replaces `&&` with `&amp;&amp;` which causes a syntax error. Use the `document.documentElement.outerHTML` approach instead if you care about that.

Comment: This converts things like `<br>` in html into `<br />` in xml... & adds things like `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.

Comment: HTML 5 documents are not valid XML, and passing the former to `serializeToString`  will have a number of potentially undesired artefacts, like every `=>` (a syntactical part of an arrow function definition in a `script` element) turn out like `=&gt;` in the serialized string, which is rejected by subsequent attempts to parse and load said document text back in the browser (e.g for displaying it as a page).

Answer (score 56):

I tried the various answers to see what is returned.  I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

The suggestion `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` returned `<head> ... </body>`

Gaby's suggestion `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;` returned the same.

The suggestion `document.documentElement.outerHTML;` returned `<html><head> ... </body></html>`
which is everything apart from the 'doctype'.

You can retrieve the doctype object with `document.doctype;`  This returns an object, not a string, so if you need to extract the details as strings for all doctypes up to and including HTML5 it is described here: [Get DocType of an HTML as string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088972/get-doctype-of-an-html-as-string-with-javascript)

I only wanted HTML5, so the following was enough for me to create the whole document:

`alert('<!DOCTYPE HTML>' + '\n' + document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

Comment: This is the most complete answer and should be accepted. As of 2016, browser compatibility is complete, and mentioning it in detail (as in the currently accepted answer) is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 51):

I believe `document.documentElement.outerHTML` should return that for you.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML), `outerHTML` is supported in Firefox 11, Chrome 0.2, Internet Explorer 4.0, Opera 7, Safari 1.3, Android, Firefox Mobile 11, IE Mobile, Opera Mobile, and Safari Mobile. `outerHTML` is in the [DOM Parsing and Serialization](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#outerhtml) specification.

The MSDN page on the [`outerHTML` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534310(VS.85).aspx) notes that it is supported in IE 5+. Colin's answer links to the W3C quirksmode page, which offers a good comparison of cross-browser compatibility (for other DOM features too).

Comment: Not all browsers support this.

Comment: @Colin: Yeah, good point. From experience, I seem to remember that both IE 6+ and Firefox support it, though the quirksmode page you linked suggests otherwise...

Comment: Firefox does not support OuterHTML.  It is IE proprietary. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#Generate_and_manipulate_content

Comment: @Jesse: Yes, evidently. Might have been innerHTML that I used, which does have cross-browser support.

Comment: Is there a way to get everything including the doctype and the html tags?

Comment: This answer is nearly identical to Colin's (and refers to it). Merge maybe?

Comment: Mine was first, actually. :P

Comment: @Noldorin, Why do you quote MSDN for?

Comment: @Pacerier: Why *did* I quote it, you mean? This was over 8 years ago haha! But the truth is, I think I just wanted to highlight IE support. And since IE is Microsoft-produced, MSDN seemed like a good authority on it...

Answer (score 11):

You can also do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

You will not get the Doctype or html tag, but everything else...

Answer (score 7):

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Comment: Not all browsers support this.

Comment: Supported in Firefox 11, Chrome 0.2, Internet Explorer 4.0, Opera 7, Safari 1.3, Android, Firefox Mobile 11, IE Mobile, Opera Mobile, and Safari Mobile ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML)). `outerHTML` is in the [DOM Parsing and Serialization](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#outerhtml) specification.

Comment: Colin's answer is more detailed.

Answer (score 6):

PROBABLY ONLY IE:

```
>     webBrowser1.DocumentText
```

for FF up from 1.0:

```
//serialize current DOM-Tree incl. changes/edits to ss-variable
var ns = new XMLSerializer();
var ss= ns.serializeToString(document);
alert(ss.substr(0,300));
```

may work in FF. (Shows up the VERY FIRST 300 characters from the VERY beginning of source-text, mostly doctype-defs.)

BUT be aware, that the normal "Save As"-Dialog of FF MIGHT NOT save the current state of the page, rather the originallly loaded X/h/tml-source-text !!
(a POST-up of ss to some temp-file and redirect to that might deliver a saveable source-text WITH the changes/edits prior made to it.)

Although FF surprises by good recovery on "back" and a NICE inclusion of states/values on "Save (as) ..." **for input-like FIELDS, textarea** etc. , not on elements in contenteditable/ designMode...

If NOT a xhtml- resp. xml-file (mime-type, NOT just filename-extension!), one may use document.open/write/close to SET the appr. content to the source-layer, that will be saved on user's save-dialog from the File/Save menue of FF.
see:
http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite resp.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write

Neutral to questions of X(ht)ML, try a "view-source:http://..." as the value of the src-attrib of an (script-made!?) iframe, - to access an iframes-document in FF:

`<iframe-elementnode>.contentDocument`, see google "mdn contentDocument" for appr. members, like 'textContent' for instance.
'Got that years ago and no like to crawl for it. If still of urgent need, mention this, that I got to dive in ...

Answer (score 3):

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Comment: This doesn't return the `<html ...>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

To also get things outside the `<html>...</html>`, most importantly the `<!DOCTYPE ...>` declaration, you could walk through document.childNodes, turning each into a string:

```
const html = [...document.childNodes]
    .map(node => nodeToString(node))
    .join('\n') // could use '' instead, but whitespace should not matter.

function nodeToString(node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            return node.outerHTML
        case node.TEXT_NODE:
            // Text nodes should probably never be encountered, but handling them anyway.
            return node.textContent
        case node.COMMENT_NODE:
            return `<!--${node.textContent}-->`
        case node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            return doctypeToString(node)
        default:
            throw new TypeError(`Unexpected node type: ${node.nodeType}`)
    }
}
```

I published this code as [document-outerhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/document-outerhtml) on npm.

---

*edit* Note the code above depends on a function `doctypeToString`; its implementation could be as follows (code below is published on npm as [doctype-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/doctype-to-string)):

```
function doctypeToString(doctype) {
    if (doctype === null) {
        return ''
    }
    // Checking with instanceof DocumentType might be neater, but how to get a
    // reference to DocumentType without assuming it to be available globally?
    // To play nice with custom DOM implementations, we resort to duck-typing.
    if (!doctype
        || doctype.nodeType !== doctype.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE
        || typeof doctype.name !== 'string'
        || typeof doctype.publicId !== 'string'
        || typeof doctype.systemId !== 'string'
    ) {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a DocumentType')
    }
    const doctypeString = `<!DOCTYPE ${doctype.name}`
        + (doctype.publicId ? ` PUBLIC "${doctype.publicId}"` : '')
        + (doctype.systemId
            ? (doctype.publicId ? `` : ` SYSTEM`) + ` "${doctype.systemId}"`
            : ``)
        + `>`
    return doctypeString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Probably not the right way but I can understand it when I see it.

Comment: This is incorrect because it won't return the `<html...>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `outerHTML` for elements (the main `<html>` container), and `XMLSerializer` for anything else including `<!DOCTYPE>`, random comments outside the `<html>` container, or whatever else might be there. It seems that whitespace isn't preserved outside the `<html>` element, so I'm adding newlines by default with `sep="\n"`.

```js
function get_document_html(sep="\n") {
    let html = "";
    let xml = new XMLSerializer();
    for (let n of document.childNodes) {
        if (n.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            html += n.outerHTML + sep;
        else
            html += xml.serializeToString(n) + sep;
    }
    return html;
}

console.log(get_document_html().slice(0, 200));
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you want to get everything outside the DOCTYPE:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

or this if you want the doctype too:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.doctype) + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using querySelector

```js
const html = document.querySelector("html").outerHTML;
console.log(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need doctype html and should work fine in IE11, Edge and Chrome. I used below code it works fine.

```
function downloadPage(element, event) {
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);

    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {
        document.execCommand('SaveAs', '1', 'page.html');
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        if(isChrome) {
            element.setAttribute('href','data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent('<!doctype html>' + document.documentElement.outerHTML));
        }
        element.setAttribute('download', 'page.html');
    }
}
```

and in your anchor tag use like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="downloadPage(this,event);" download>Download entire page.</a>
```

**Example**

```js
    function downloadPage(element, event) {
     var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    
     if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) {
      document.execCommand('SaveAs', '1', 'page.html');
      event.preventDefault();
     } else {
      if(isChrome) {
                element.setAttribute('href','data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent('<!doctype html>' + document.documentElement.outerHTML));
      }
      element.setAttribute('download', 'page.html');
     }
    }
```

```html
I just need doctype html and should work fine in IE11, Edge and Chrome. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<p>
<a href="#" onclick="downloadPage(this,event);"  download><h2>Download entire page.</h2></a></p>

<p>Some image here</p>

<p><img src="https://placeimg.com/250/150/animals"/></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.documentElement`.

Same Question answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289396/2164160

Comment: That question should be closed as pretty much a duplicate of this one, which is much older. Anyway, the interesting part is that you need `.outerHTML` and to get the `document.doctype`, and the most complete answer is [Paolo's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26905999/1269037).

Answer (score -3):

You have to iterate through the document childNodes and getting the outerHTML content.

in VBA it looks like this

```
For Each e In document.ChildNodes
    Put ff, , e.outerHTML & vbCrLf
Next e
```

using this, allows you to get all elements of the web page including < !DOCTYPE > node if it exists

Answer (score -10):

The correct way is actually:

webBrowser1.DocumentText