# javascript, current html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firebug

Is there a javascript script that returns the *current html* of the window? I mean the content of the *webinspector* or *Firebug* html tab.

Comment: This extension has a "View Generated Source" option which will provide what you're asking: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get entire document HTML as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/get-entire-document-html-as-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- this has been discussed previously here on StackOverflow:

[How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/get-entire-document-html-as-string)

In short,

```
var txt = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
alert(txt);
```

Comment: That is the html source, I mean the results after javascripts, ajax, etc...I would have the html that describes the current visualization in the browser window, or the current DOM

Comment: @caporiccirob that's exactly what this gives you.

Comment: Oh, ok, but with iframes it did not work, that was my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this example, it is useful for you

```
       <html>

      <style type="text/css">
       body {
         margin: 3em;
          }

   #Wrapper {
   background: #aaa;
   min-width: 200px;
   padding: 10px;        
  }

    #Panel {
   width: 300px;
   background: green;
    position:absoulte;
  }
</style>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  function CallPrint(strid)
    {
     var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
var WinPrint = window.open('', '',    'left=30,top=0,width=600,height=600,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,status=0');

           var ss='<html><body>' + prtContent.innerHTML + '</html></body>';
          alert(ss);
       WinPrint.document.write(ss);

            WinPrint.document.close();



     }

  </script>
    <body>

    <div id="Wrapper">
     <div id="first">Panel</div>
   <div id="second">Panel</div>
   <div id="third">Panel</div>
   <div id="fourth">Panel</div>
   <a href="#" onClick="CallPrint('Wrapper');">Click TO View Full Html</a>
      </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```