# WebRenderer Swing and Server Edition

Tags: java, browser

I am using [WebRenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/) to export HTML5 pages to images on the server. The problem is that the only edition that supports HTML5 is the swing edition. However, I can use the jar files from the swing edition and create a new `IMozillaBrowserCanvas` object and not link it to a JFrame/JPanel and have it convert the html5 page without a GUI.

Are there any differences between the swing and server edition when just using `IMozillaBrowserCanvas`? The only info I could was find was this:

> The WebRenderer Server Edition 4.0 scales better in server and
>   headless environments than any other Java browser SDK due to the fact
>   that rendering is not performed on the Swing Thread. Keeping rendering
>   off the Swing Thread, and multi-threading the rendering leads to major
>   improvements in scalability. [[Source](http://www.java.net/node/667832)]

Also, what is happening in the back end when the `spawnMozilla()` method is being called from the `BrowserFactory` class? To my knowledge, this is just a pure java browser and not running xserver in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted the developer from WebRenderer. He said:

> There are mostly internal architectural differences between the Server
>   and Swing Editions of WebRenderer. The Server Edition was designed
>   primarily for creating images of pages, whereas the Swing Edition is a
>   fully functional browser. However, this does not prevent the Swing
>   Edition from being used efficiently to generate page images.
>
> The API is similar, although the Server has convenience methods for
>   different sizes/types of image generation, and the Swing Edition has more
>   features available. The version of the underlying Mozilla browser is
>   much more recent in the Swing Edition, so it is capable of rendering
>   pages that make use of technologies such as HTML5.
>
> While the rendering is all done in Java, the Mozilla component needs
>   to be handled natively for each platform. It does not run an xserver,
>   but the spawnMozilla() call will set up these native components, they
>   are extracted to the .webrendererswing6 directory in the user home
>   directory by default.