# How to find text in a window?

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get entire document HTML as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/get-entire-document-html-as-string)

I want to find all instances of a regex pattern within a webpage. I want to do something like this:

```
    myWindow=window.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript','_self','');

    var n=myWindow.document.match(/Jav/g);  //  This line obviously doesn't work but how would I do this?

    myWindow.document.write(n);
```

Is there a way to put all the text from the webpage into a string, and from that point search the string? Or, is there a way to retrieve the HTML source code, which could then be searched? How would I do this?

Comment: The Same Origin Policy prevents you from accessing this content.

Comment: Can I do this with an browser extension to avoid the "same origin policy"?