# Javascript: Get current page CURRENT source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML and I need to get page source of this html.

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

or

```
$.ajax({
async: true,
type: 'GET',
cache: false,
url: window.location.href,
success: function(data) {
   alert(data);
}
});
```

is working, but they display originally source. If I change html (by jQuery, for example), they don't read my changes.

Is it possible read CURRENT source of page?

Comment: You dont want the Source, but the DOM?

Comment: How about `document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].outerHTML`?

Comment: Why do you think that `document.documentElement.outerHTML` would not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Answer (score 11):

Tried it on chrome and it works. Use

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Funnily enough your code also worked

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Check out the html printed to the console in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bruno/nmRJ5/1/). It actually contains the changes made by jQuery.

Comment: Note that this will include that have been made to the DOM. For example, some plugins inject HTML, and if you resize a <textarea>, it will add a height and width attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery you can do this by:

```
$( 'body' ).html();
```

For example.

Or convert to String:

```
$( 'body' ).html().toString();
```

Comment: it's not whole page, i guess?

Comment: @indapublic it's body, for HTML use `$( 'html' )`

Comment: Isn't it remarkable that the author `.outerHTML` doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to grab the element and use the html method:

```
$('.selector').html();
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution, source of a document usually embedded in html tag
so use `$('html').html()`, you will get everything between html tags.