# How to check if a page contains a given keyword? (Then execute function if keyword exists)

Tags: javascript

What's the easiest way to check if a loaded page contains a certain keyword or string? My intent is to execute a function if the text exists anywhere on the page.

The closest thing I've found is:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("my keyword(s)") != -1) {do something}
```

But this only checks if the URL contains the keyword.

Comment: Including html tag names? If you want to search the entire source of the document, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/get-entire-document-html-as-string). Also, I would look into regular expressions as well.

Comment: Not including html tag names, unless the easiest way to do this is to include them.

Comment: So you just want the visible text?

Comment: Yes, for this question, that's all I'm inquiring about. But thank you for bringing tag names to my attention. I initially didn't take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this:

```
if ( !!~document.body.textContent.indexOf("my keyword(s)") 
     || !!~window.location.href.indexOf("my keyword(s)") ) {
    // Keyword found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `window.document.body.innerText`, you get the entire text of the body, without tags.