# Not able to fetch table rows from an Array stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I have a local storage key name `"A"` which contains an array of table rows. When I alert the whole array it shows `[object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement]`

But when I loop over the array I am not getting the object in my variable, instead I get `[` only.

How to properly fetch the table row objects from the array.

Here is my code :

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("A") !== null) {

        var lArray = localStorage.getItem("A");
        alert(lArray);   // alerts [object HTMLTableRowElement],[object HTMLTableRowElement]
        for(var i=0 ; i < lArray.length ; i++)
        {
            alert(lArray[i]);   // alerts [
        }

    }
```

And here is how I am putting the table rows in my local storage

```
 var favA = [];
 function addRow()
 {
    var tableRow = document.createElement("TR");
    var trID = "Tr";
    tableRow.setAttribute("id", trID);

    favA.push(tableRow);    

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("A", favA);

    }
```

Comment: are you stringifying before putting into storage? I don't think inserting raw objects into localStorages work

Comment: No, should I stringify the TableRow object before putting it in local storage?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532489/how-to-store-javascript-html-dom-document-to-locastorage

Comment: yep, that's what I thought. it calls the toString() method every time you trying inserting an object into the local storage

Comment: better use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Comment: I am able to get JSON object using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse but I am still not able to use tableRow in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `JSON.stringify` on an `HTMLElement`. Use `.outerHTML` to get the HTML string. Keep in mind these can get quite long...

Use a `DocumentFragment`'s `innerHTML` or the DOM's innerHTML directly to parse the string back to an element.

```js
var mockLocalStorage = (function mock() {
  var store = {};
  
  return {
    getItem: function(k) { return store[k]; },
    setItem: function(k, v) { store[k] = v; }
  }
}());

var myRow = document.querySelector("tr");
var myRowStr = myRow.outerHTML;

// This won't work:
// JSON.stringify(myRow)) // returns "{}"

var toLocalStorage = function() {
   mockLocalStorage.setItem("_test", myRowStr); 
}

var fromLocalStorage = function() {
   document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML +=
     mockLocalStorage.getItem("_test"); 
  
}

toLocalStorage();
fromLocalStorage();
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```