# save appended children in electron

Tags: html

So I have a script that appends text boxes and I want to save the text boxes, by this I mean when I reopen the app it will load the text boxes with their value and stuff. I am asking this question because I have searched the answer for 2 days and still can't find anything related to this. Any help will be appreciated!

```html
<body>
  <form class="myformclass" style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size:20px;" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input class="addcommandbtn"type="button" id="addCommand" style="width: 6.5%;" value="+ Command"> 
    <input class="addcommandbtn"type="button" id="removeCommand" style="width: 7.2%;" value="- Command" onclick="removeCommandFunc()"> 
    <input class="addcommandbtn"type="button" id="saveCommands" style="width: 4.2%;" value="Save Commands" onclick="SaveToLocalStorage()">
    <input class="addcommandbtn"type="button" id="loadCommands" style="width: 4.2%;" value="load Commands" onclick="load()">
    <select name="commandslist" id="commandslist" size="18%" style="height: 59%;width: 15%; display: block; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; border-radius: 6px; margin-top: 5px;"></select>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function showmenu() {
      ipcRenderer.invoke('chooseloc');
  }
  function commadnspage() {
      location.href="./commands.html";
  }
  function homepage(){
      location.href="./index.html";
  }
  function removeCommandFunc() { 
      var d = document.getElementById("commandslist"); 
      d.remove(d.selectedIndex); 
  } 
</script>
<script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

    </script>
<script>
  var commands = []; 
  function createCommandField() {
    var input = document.createElement('option');
    input.style.marginTop = "1%";
    input.textContent = "command";
    input.name = 'Commands[]';
    input.style.display = 'block'
    input.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff';
    input.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
    input.style.borderRadius = '6px';
    input.style.height = "2%";
    input.style.padding = '5px 30px';
    input.style.fontFamily="Arial";
    input.style.fontWeight="bold";
    input.style.fontSize="17px";
    commands.push(input);
    return input;
  }
  function SaveToLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem('commands', JSON.stringify(commands));
  }
  
  function load(){
      
        document.getElementById('commandslist').appendChild(localStorage.getItem(`commands`, JSON.parse(commands)));     
      
  }  
  
  
  var select = document.getElementById('commandslist');
  document.getElementById('addCommand').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    select.appendChild(createCommandField());
  });

</script>
```

Comment: can you share your code how you append these text boxes. Also when you use electron than use this as tag

Comment: function createCommandField() {
    var input = document.createElement('option');
    input.style.marginTop = "1%";
    input.textContent = "command";
    input.name = 'Commands[]';
    input.style.display = 'block'
    input.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff';
    input.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
    input.style.borderRadius = '6px';
    input.style.height = "2%";
    input.style.padding = '5px 30px';
    input.style.fontFamily="Arial";
    input.style.fontWeight="bold";
    input.style.fontSize="17px";
    return input;
  }

Comment: this is my first posts so idk how to make the code more readable

Comment: this is a function that is called when someone clicks a button

Comment: Add it to your question, click edit than paste it inside mark it and click the symbol of the two curly braces

Comment: or wait I will do a snippet

Comment: i have a problem i cant add a part of the code

Comment: i will add it here       
 var select = document.getElementById('commandslist');
  document.getElementById('addCommand').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    select.appendChild(createCommandField());
  });

Comment: you can also do a snippet, the symbol next to the braces.
So appending works what is the problem here? I dont know what you mean by "storing"?

Comment: like when i close the app

Comment: and start it again i would like to load the last appended text boxes

Comment: where do you close it when you restart the app the instructions will be exectuted in the same order and it will still the same result,
Or do you append based on user input or something?

Comment: when i press a button it will run that function but i want to keep the text boxes after i restart the app

Comment: I think you can use localSorage for this https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Well I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You can store your elements in `Window.localStorage()`

```
myStorage = localStorage;

function createCommandField() {
  var input = document.createElement('option');
  input.style.marginTop = "1%";
  input.textContent = "command";
  input.name = 'Commands[]';
  input.style.display = 'block'
  input.style.boxShadow = 'inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff';
  input.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
  input.style.borderRadius = '6px';
  input.style.height = "2%";
  input.style.padding = '5px 30px';
  input.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
  input.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  input.style.fontSize = "17px";
  return input;
 
}

let select = document.getElementById('bl');
let opt2 = createCommandField();

select.appendChild(opt2);


localStorage.setItem("doc", document.documentElement.innerHTML);

var retrievedObject1 = localStorage.getItem('doc');

console.log(retrievedObject1)
```

Comment: it didnt work maybe because i did something wrong coz i want to save every appended children with a save button and load them when i run the program

Comment: wait lemme try something

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532489/how-to-store-javascript-html-dom-document-to-locastorageI will update it

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at load (commands.html:303)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (commands.html:255)

Comment: Have updated the answer in your retrievedObject1 is then the whole page

Comment: changed the console.log to alert and it shows the whole html script

Comment: ty so much now its working i used the fs library to re write the script

Comment: You're welcome :) if you think this was helpful then mark it as accepted the sign below the up/downvote

Comment: one more question tho how do i use app.getpath to get the .html file

Comment: in which context? what is app?

Comment: like when i save the file

Comment: when i rewrite it i need to specify the path

Comment: this depends on your system. Unix based I would do something like `let path="~/Documents/Project/" `