# Is it possible to replace text without selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I use a [javascript](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) to convert markdown to html.

If I add `<span id="printHello></span>` to the markdown, after conversion, I could still use `getElementById()` to get the reference. However, there is one exception:

```
var abc = true;
<span id="printHello></span>
var def = false;
```

If the tag is added inside a code block, it will get escaped during the conversion. I can no longer get the element.

So I am thinking if I can add an identifier text, replacing the identifier text after the markdown has been converted to html. Like this:

```
var abc = true;
I_am_an_identifier
var def = false;
```

After converting, I get this:

```
<pre><code>var abc = true;
I_am_an_identifier
var def = false;
</code></pre>
```

So I can replace `I_am_an_identifier` to `<span id="printHello></span>`

Is it possible to replace by means of contents?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't get what you're going for...

Comment: [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Comment: I was about to tell you to use regexp but, [you know...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5054380)

Comment: In your example, you *could* get the content of the `span` if its ID had a closing quote, even if it's within a `code` element:  https://jsfiddle.net/07qpd5mk/

Comment: @JamesHill I am doing some real-time preview of markdowns with external editor. I need to trace the editor cursor position so that I can implement auto scroll. I add an empty tag to indicate cursor position. The problem occurs when the cursor is in a code block.

Comment: use javascript labels I'm pretty sure your convertor will not strip them down too. Than use your html injector routine to replace the identifier with your span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for your question is, you can replace a string in your HTML with another using the `replace` method.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('I_am_an_identifier', '<span id="printHello"></span>');
```

Note that this will replace the first instance of `I_am_an_identifier`, including any instances in your HTML code (e.g. class names etc..), so use with caution.

To replace all instances of the target string, use a simple regular expression with the global flag:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/I_am_an_identifier/g, '<span id="printHello"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

***Javascript has Labels***

Fortunately you can use your *identifier* keyword, ( let's say you chose "printHello" )  in form of a JavaScript *Label*:

```
<pre><code>var abc = true;
printHello: 
var def = false;
</code></pre>
```

than you can find and replace it with whichever thing you like.