# How do I render HTMLDocument type in React render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, xpath

I have something like this

```
public render(){

  let htmlRender = "<html><body><h2>Children</h2>Joe has three kids:<br/><ul><li>Linn Fenimore Cooper Cary (married writer <a href='Ved Mehta'>Ved Mehta</a> in 1983)</li><li>kid2</li><li>kid3</li></ul></body></html>";

  const doc  = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlRender,'text/html');


  let ele = doc.evaluate("/html/body/ul/li[1]/a[1]", doc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
  ele.singleNodeValue.style.background = 'pink';

  return (
        <div className="details-block context-block">
            <h5>Context</h5>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:doc.body.toString()}} /> --> This returns [object HTMLBodyElement]
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is what I am doing above - Taking a html string converting it into a HTML object. Then parsing that using Xpath. Manipulating it(adding the color) and then I want to display it. But it appears as `[object HTMLBodyElement]`. what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: try printing `doc.body.toString()` to console and see what you get. edit: yeah, `doc.body.toString()` -> "[object HTMLBodyElement]". Use `doc.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out in Chrome's console and I think your issue is `doc.body.toString()`.

```
> let x = "<html>...</html>";
> let y = new DOMParser().parseFromString(x, "text/html");
> y                 // #document
> y.body            // <body>​…​</body>​
> y.body.toString() // "[object HTMLBodyElement]"
```

Instead of `toString()`, use `innerHTML` (or outerHTML if you want the `<body/>` tags).

```
> y.body.innerHTML  // "<h2>Children</h2> ..."
```

What's happening is you are creating a React `div` element with the literal string contents "[object HTMLBodyElement]" instead of the contents of `doc.body` - `doc.body.innerHTML`

edit: according to comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string) you should actually be using `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)` - up to you; whatever works.