# How to use JavaScript to count occurence of a word in entire HTML webpage versus just in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a JSON report that I append to my webpage that monitors a server's processes and every processes that is running it returns the string "runn1ng".

I want to do a summary at the top of the webpage that says:

```
___ out of 10 processes are running.
```

The `___` number will be the dynamic number that is counted by JavaScript to see how many "runn1ng" appear on the webpage.

I have seen some documentation on here on how to count occurrences of a string within an array, but I am curious if there is a way to count the string occurrence on the entire webpage.

Comment: How about assign them to div with unique class, then aggregate a string from the content selection of that class?

Comment: why not get that data from the JSON instead of the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var documentHtml = document.documentElement.outerHTML; // Gets page's HTML
var occurences = (documentHtml.match(/runn1ng/g) || []).length; // Searches the page for occurrences
```

However, as others have mentioned, it's most likely a better and more maintainable solution to have the JSON expose the number of running processes.

[How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

[How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var n = html.search("runn1ng");
```