# Manipulate HTML Input field with no "Value" attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm struggling with an automation task where the HTML site has an input field, but when I search it out in DOM Explorer it looks like this:

```
<input name="txtFirewall" id="txtFirewall" type="text">
```

As you can see, there is no value attribute. Once you give in smthing manually to the search field it changes like this:

```
<input name="txtFirewall" id="txtFirewall" type="text">value="Something">
```

How can I add the Value attribute and assign value to it with python? Can it be even done with Selenium?

Comment: There was nothing useful here? https://www.google./search?q=add+value+attribute+selenium ? I see several interesting links

Comment: `'element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("txtFirewall")` and then  `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','whatever')", element)'` according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can help you:

```
search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("txtFirewall")
search_field.send_keys("Something")
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

To add the `value` attribute and assign the value `'Something'` to it you can use the following code block :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#txtFirewall.txtFirewall")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','Something')", element)
```