# get all innerHTML of a parent window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get all the `innerHTML` of my web form, here's what I'm doing:

I need to be able to do this for parent of the window. So to begin, using var = dialog I get the window.parent as shown below:

```
function PrintForm() {

   var dialog = window.parent.wdwBHForm;

}
```

Now I'm trying to use dialog (parent of window) to get all innerHTML, because my end goal is to be able to print it.

```
var html = dialog.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML
```

I've tried this line above, but  it doesn't work.

I also have infragistics control that I need to get `innerHTML` for - I hope I'd be able to do the same.

Any idea?

Comment: @mason - dialog is the parent of my window.

Comment: it says it in the function var dialog = window.parent.wdwBHForm

Comment: @mason I am trying to get innerHTML of my parent window. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can do that in the following way:

```js
function PrintForm() {
   var innerHtml = window.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
   // If you want to access the parent window
   // var innerHtml = window.parent.document.documentElement.innerHTML;
   console.log(innerHtml);
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  UserName : <input type="text" name="userName"> 
</form>
<button onclick="PrintForm()">Show InnerHTML</button>
```

Comment: @mason, but I think there is no `parent` on `window` object.

Comment: @mason, since OP didn't provide any `HTML`, I did it with a single window object....thanks for the point though.

Comment: @mason, I answered with `May be` so that OP can get some idea to solve his problem even if he fails to make us understand his context fully.

Comment: @mason, I have seen lot of answers like that and I feel there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I appreciate the help with this @Mamun

Comment: I also appreciate @mason your comments

Comment: @mason, then I have to change the `HTML` as well. What I can do is mention this for child-parent window situation, which eventually I did...thanks again for helping me to update the answer.