# Browser extension to check substring in html code from website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
str.toString();
var substring = "raju";
if(str.includes(substring)){
alert('found');
}
```

i want to parse the html as string for a particular website and checking for substring in that html code.
But it not working, please help!

Comment: Have you tried `document.body.innerText` instead of `toString()` on the array?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[0]` to get first element from DOM collection and then access `innerText` property. `toString` is useless, hence removed

```
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText;
var substring = "raju";
if(str.includes(substring)){
alert('found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.body.innerHTML` to get the HTML contents in a string. Example:

```
const str = document.body.innerHTML;
const substring = "raju";

if (str.includes(substring)){
 alert('found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Includes is not supported on Internet Explorer. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility), so best way to do that is use indexOf

```
var str = document.body.innerHTML;
var substring = "raju";
if(str.indexOf(substring) >= 0) {
//your stuff
}
```

Comment: @EdwinShakil please accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

This works and other suggested functions shouldn't be used. Ref: [How to get the entire document HTML as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817218/how-to-get-the-entire-document-html-as-a-string#answer-35917295)

```js
    const str =new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)
    const substring = "raju";
    
    if (str.includes(substring)){
     alert('found');
    }
```