# How to make a button in HTML that will send the current page of a website via email?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Let's say I have a website where there is a button. When you click on this button the website will send the current page html (either as the body of an email or as an attachment ex: index.html) to a specific email address. Is this possible? If so, how? (I want to do it in either with html tags or javascript).

It's like sending a form but instead you send an html page.

Comment: You cannot directly send an email using javascript. You can however accomplish this using nodejs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript

Comment: there is the mailto html tag no?

Comment: @Nassims, `mailto` in HTML is just a custom prefix for an `href` target. You can configure it on anchor tags like, `<a href="mailto:john.doe@example.com">Email John</a>`, and most user-agents (browsers) will then open the system's default mailing client when that link is clicked. You can also make that populate with specific text by including `mailto:bob@example.com?subject=some subject value&body=some body value`, but the contents must be `text/plain`. Although, here is an interesting possible solution: [StackOverflow: mailto link with HTML body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699855/2694511).

Comment: Did you get the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing looks to be a use case for [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/). Assumption here is that you're using Node.js as your backend. There are many options for other languages [pypi-mailer](https://pypi.org/project/mailer/) being a common option for python.

Regardless, you would need to have a html form (or a default option of email)

```
<form action="/sendMail">
  <label for="email">Email: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Enter your email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be send to an endpoint /sendMail".</p>
```

Then you would need Javascript on the front-end to actually get the object. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817225/7654532) answer is what you're looking for here.

[This](https://blog.mailtrap.io/sending-emails-with-nodemailer/) link explains how to actually use nodemailer to send an email.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Nassims did you try this out?

Comment: I'm not using a backend. Everything is done on the frontend so I can't use node.