# javascript/jquery script to calculate html page size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, size

I'm looking for a script to calculate and display the size / weight (in kb) of an html page, like on this page : https://solar.lowtechmagazine.com/

page size : 403.86KB

the total size of all the ressources (text, img, scripts...)

I've found a Pelican plugin : https://git.vvvvvvaria.org/rra/page_metadata but I need to use javascript / jquery.

any ideas ?

I can't find any ressources online, any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

For the main page you can use this:

```js
let mainHTMLsize = (new Blob([new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)], {type: 'text/html'})).size;
```

(With thanks to [Eric Aigner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35917295/204723).)

I turn it into a `Blob` because `(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)).length` would give the number of UTF-16 code units, whereas `blob.size` is the number of bytes.

Then I think  [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/decodedBodySize) should sort you out for the rest:

```js
const p = performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
for (let i=0; i < p.length; i++) 
{
  console.log(`${p[i].name} decodedBodySize = ${p[i].decodedBodySize}`);
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell - does your `mainHTMLsize` include any xml serialisation artifacts?  eg `<xml version=`?  How is it better/different from `document.body.outerHTML.length`?  Does it include images and their sizes? (not saying it's wrong, just curious)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, it includes the whole text of the document. I believe `outerHTML` misses some, e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It doesn't include images, etc., that's what the rest is for.

Comment: @freedomn-m you can do a comparison in the console. `(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document)).length - document.documentElement.outerHTML.length`

Comment: Yes, they're different, hence the question to determine what's different/why , which you answered fine.  I was trying to see what was in the blob, rather than the output of the serialise, so that helps.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code, works like a charm :

```
var res = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');

var totalSize = res.reduce((size, item) => {
  size += item.decodedBodySize;
  return size;
}, 0);

var totalSizeKB = totalSize / Math.pow(1024,1)

var totalSizeKB_decimal = (Math.round(totalSizeKB * 100)/100).toFixed(2);

$(".size span").html(totalSizeKB_decimal + " KB");
```